# What does new ClassName[0] do? (Java 8)

Tags: java

What does this syntax do, with square brackets around the number?

```
new Integer[0];
```

I've found it in a codebase I'm maintaining but I can't find any documentation on it. It is used like this:

```
Set<Form> forms = getForms();
List<Form> formsList = Arrays.asList(forms.toArray(new Form[0]))
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a generic array in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/529085/how-to-create-a-generic-array-in-java)

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1665834/how-can-i-initialize-a-string-array-with-length-0-in-java#1665899

Comment: Unless you absolutely want a fixed-size mutable list, this is overly complicated. For most uses prefer `List<Form> formsList = new ArrayList(forms);`.

Comment: it is creating an empty `Integer` array, that is, an array that  holds `Integer` instances with size 0, that is, actually it can hold no instance of `Integer`- often used as kind of a template, or as return from some method to indicate, for example, that nothing was found

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert Set<String> to String[\]?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5982447/how-to-convert-setstring-to-string). It’s not the exact same question, but I believe that the answer to this question is there.  Or, depending on how you look at it, possible duplicate of [How can I initialize a String array with length 0 in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1665834/how-can-i-initialize-a-string-array-with-length-0-in-java)

Comment: In Java generic types are erased by compiler so `toArray` wouldn't be able to create from `Set<Form>` proper `Form[]` array because there is no information about `Form` type at runtime. Because of that you need to provide type of array as argument of `toArray`, otherwise it would return `Object[]` array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It allocates an array with length zero; e.g. `new Integer[0]` creates a zero length array of `Integer` objects.

**Why would you do that?**

Well look at the javadocs for the `form.toArray(T[])` method.   Assuming that `form` is some subtype of `Collection` they are [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#toArray-T:A-).

The purpose of the `toArray` method is to copy the elements of the target collection (e.g. your `form`) into an array:

- If the argument array is large enough to hold all elements, they are copied into that array.  The result will be the argument array.
- If the argument array is too small, a new array is allocated *with the same type as the argument array* and a length that is (just) enough to hold the elements.  The elements are then copied into the new array, and it is returned as the result.

So what the code is actually doing is copying the elements of `form` to an `Integer[]` of the right size, and then wrapping the array to give a (fixed sized) `List<Integer>`.  This can then be passed to some other code without worrying that that code might alter the original `form` collection.

Answer (score -1):

Unlike traditional array which store values like string, integer, Boolean, etc. array of objects stores objects. The array elements store the location of reference variables of the object

Syntax: 
Class obj[]= new Class[array_length]

Comment: Thank you for wanting to contribute. It’s not entirely correct, and it’s not perfectly clear how it answers the question. In Java a string is also an object. And the recommended syntax puts the square brackets right after the class name, `Class[] arr = new Class[array_length];`.